# The padding used in my menu is off by 1px between Firefox and Chrome, how do I fix this?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, padding

I've been searching through stack overflow to find an answer to this, but nothing has been helping me (or I've been adding it incorrectly).

I've set up a horizontal menu on a website for a client and am trying to center the menu items within the menu bar, however, the right and left padding is off by 1px between firefox and chrome, which makes the last menu item in the row butt up against the right edge only in Firefox. Dropping the left and right padding in firebug by 1px on the li tags in the menu makes it look like it does in Chrome with my original CSS.

The problem code seems to be on the li tags padding.

Here is a JSFiddle with my menu code (sans background images, but the problem is still evident) http://jsfiddle.net/FxznT/1/

and here is the original site I've been working into for reference: http://clients.taylordesign.com/LCBP/site/home.html

What am I missing? I am already using a CSS reset. Thanks.

Comment: looks like Chrome and FF are rendering the font spacing / width slightly different resulting in the offset in FF

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use a CSS hack to select only Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .ul.topNav li {
     padding: 16px 11px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid hacks if possible, but will do so if needed. Thanks for the code, I didn't know of that one.